# Batch file using WMIC not working correctly with TaskScheduler (but working fine from command line!)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, xcopy, taskscheduler, wmic

I decided to write a small batchfile to make daily copies of a folder and its contents. I used WMIC to properly format the date in order to name the folders automatically. While it works perfectly on the command line, it seems that it dislikes being executed by the TaskScheduler - it does make a copy of the folder, but doesn't retrieving any date, and saves the files into a folder named `-~-2-~-2`. It seems to skip the first part of the code altogether, and jump directly to the `Pad digits` part, from where it gets the `~-2` bit. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Here's my batch file:

```
@Echo off
:: Check WMIC is available
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO s_error

:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
      Set _yyyy=%%L
      Set _mm=00%%J
      Set _dd=00%%G
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
      Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
      Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%

:: Display the date/time in ISO 8601 format:
Set _date=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd%
Echo %_date%

:: Xcopy the files!

xcopy /s /i "C:\Users\Alcides\Documents\CQC_APS_TESE_DOUTORAMENTO_LaTeX" "I:\Tese-Backup\"%_date%\

GOTO:EOF

:s_error
Echo GetDate.cmd
Echo Displays date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or date format.
Echo:
Echo Returns 6 environment variables containing isodate,Year,Month,Day,hour and minute.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a quicker method for determining your date than [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic).

The following example uses [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy):

```bat
@Set "_date="
@For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" /NJH /L "\|" Null^"')Do @If Not Defined _date Set "_date=%%A-%%B-%%C"
@"%__AppDir__%XCopy.exe" "C:\Users\Alcides\Documents\CQC_APS_TESE_DOUTORAMENTO_LaTeX" "I:\Tese-Backup\%_date%\" /S
```

Comment: Please, can you clarify your code a bit, to make it more intelligible? although i have no doubts that it may work, the overall structure of it remains a bit cryptic.

Comment: Which part of it is unintelligible? and does `Set /?`, `For /?`, `RoboCopy /?`, `If /?` and `XCopy /?` not assist you enough? _BTW, I used XCopy as you had, but see no reason why you wouldn't change that for the `RoboCopy` command instead_.

Comment: For instance, I'm not understanding the logic of your Do cycle.

Comment: Still, your code looks rock solid and works like a charm! Thanks!!!

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `"%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" /NJH /L "\|" Null` inside it. You'll note that it outputs the date that you're wanting on its first line, but an error on a line below it, _(this error was deliberately introduced)_. On the openinig line of the script we undefined the variable named `_date`, so as soon as it is defined on the first line of output, we do not want to set it on the unwanted second line, overwirting the first. We therefore tell it not to set it if a value is already assigned using an `If Not Defined` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `ISODate` from `WMIC`, you should try something like this code :

```bat
@echo off
Title GET ISODATE FROM WMIC
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%
echo Today : %today%
set "year=%MyDate:~2,2%"
set "month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "day=%MyDate:~6,2%"
echo %day%%month%%year%
pause
```